# Using Pandas Python to Calculate Daytime Site Outage Duration

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to use pandas python to calculate the duration of outages during the day throughout a month (i.e., between 09:00-21:00 for the month of August). Here's an example dataframe:

```
          Adjusted_Down         Adjusted_Up
0   2019-08-11 10:31:00 2019-08-11 10:41:00
1   2019-08-14 00:13:00 2019-08-14 00:17:00
2   2019-08-03 12:02:00 2019-08-03 15:30:00
3   2019-08-21 02:46:00 2019-08-21 02:48:00
4   2019-08-26 03:07:00 2019-08-26 03:19:00
..                  ...                 ...
222 2019-08-25 08:46:00 2019-08-25 09:06:00
223 2019-08-30 18:23:00 2019-08-30 18:33:00
224 2019-08-21 17:23:00 2019-08-21 17:27:00
225 2019-08-27 02:10:00 2019-08-27 02:14:00
226 2019-08-27 23:14:00 2019-08-27 23:20:00
```

I've tried to set parameters for a start time and end time and then tried calculating the difference between the two.

```
data = pd.read_excel('lab.xlsx')
site_open = data[(data.Adjusted_Down >= '09:00:00')]
site_close = data[(data.Adjusted_Down <= '21:00:00')]
data['daytime'] = data['site_open'] - data['site_close']
data['daytime'] = data['daytime']/np.timedelta64(1, 'm')
```

From comments I've tried updating it to the following:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp
import pytz
from pytz import all_timezones
import datetime
from datetime import time
from threading import Timer
import time
import xlrd
import xlwt
import numpy as np
import xlsxwriter

data = pd.read_excel('lab.xlsx')
data['duration'] = data['Adjusted_Up'] - data['Adjusted_Down']
data['duration'] = data['duration']/np.timedelta64(1,'m')
s = data.apply(lambda row: pd.date_range(row['Adjusted_Down'], row['Adjusted_Up'], freq='T'), axis=1).explode()
s.dt.time.between(time(9), time(21)).sum()
```

What I would expect is the duration of daytime outages between 09:00-21:00. The errors I'm receiving are:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Savers\Python\Python3 - Master\lab.py", line 18, in <module>
    s.dt.time.between(time(9), time(21)).sum()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: `site_open` is not a column, so you are getting the error your are showing

Comment: @SH-SF I thought I had defined site_open as data from 'Adjusted_Down' with anything past 09:00:00? Do I have to insert it into the dataframe and then find the difference?

Comment: The way you defined ```site_open``` and ```site_close```, these are just variables. To make the columns of dataframe, you need to do like this : ```df[site_open] = ..``` and similar for site_close

Comment: `df[site_open]=data[(data.Adjusted_Down >= '09:00:00')]` will not work. create a new dataframe `dfn=data[(data.Adjusted_Down >= '09:00:00') & (data.Adjusted_Down <= '21:00:00')]` & then do your calculations on that

Comment: Also, in the line ```df[site_open]=data[(data.Adjusted_Down >= '09:00:00')]```, you are comparing a _datetime_ string with _time_ string. You should convert them to time strings too. A way to do this is this : ```data[data.Adjusted_Down.apply(lambda x : x.split(' ')[1]) > ='09:00:00'] ```. What this does is convert the datetime string to time string by splitting at the empty space and then comparing only the second part (which is time without date)

Comment: @OsamaArshadDar I appreciate the distinction and I was wondering how I would separate the datetime string so that it would parse just the time without the date. When I ran `data[data.Adjusted_Down.apply(lambda x : x.split(' ')[1]) > == '09:00:00']` I'm getting `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` at = '09:00:00'

Comment: @SH-SF I made some changes to the post with updated code examples but am still not able to get daytime outages in minutes. Thanks for all the help so far!

Comment: Try using `to_datetime` to convert *Adjusted_Down* and *Adjusted_Up* column & then subtract them normally. You can also use `dt.hour` to subset the hours for each day between 9AM & 9PM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This answer assumes you are on pandas 0.25 or later)

If the data is not too big , the simplest way is to explode the down time by minute then count how many of them fall between 9:00 and 21:00:

```
from datetime import time
s = df.apply(lambda row: pd.date_range(row['Adjusted_Down'], row['Adjusted_Up'], freq='T'), axis=1).explode()
s.dt.time.between(time(9), time(21)).sum()
```

If you want to group by monnth, it only takes a little more work:

```
s = df.apply(lambda row: pd.date_range(row['Adjusted_Down'], row['Adjusted_Up'], freq='T'), axis=1).explode()
downtime = pd.DataFrame({
    'Month': s.astype('datetime64[M]'),
    'IsDayTime': s.dt.time.between(time(9), time(21))
})
downtime.groupby('Month')['IsDayTime'].sum()
```

Haven't tested performance though. Let me know if it's too slow on your dataset.

Comment: I love the method and approach but I'm getting an error `s.dt.time.between(time(9), time(21)).sum()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`

Comment: Did you type `import time` or `from datetime import time`? The first is a module used for benchmarking (timing) function execution. The second is a function that creates a calendar time

Comment: I do have `import time` and `from datetime import time` at the beginning of my code, I'm still getting the same traceback error that `'module' object is not callable`

Comment: I've updated the original post to show what I've been using.

Comment: You have a name clash here. Since `import time` comes later, `time` refers to the module, not the function. You can alias this module away like this `import time as t`

Comment: Thank you so much! Silly question but to re-insert I would just use something like `data.insert(2, 'open', s, allow_duplicates = True)` right? I'm trying to avoid a `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis` error.